# PrimeFaces slider - colored selected region

Tags: jquery-ui, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to make colored selection region when using PrimeFaces slider component. So what i'm trying to do is, when user set slider value to something, selected value is colored from 0 to chosen value (look at image).

[image: what i want to make]

I know that PF are using jQuery ui and we can make this happen in jQuery like `$("#slider").slider({range: "min"});` and then define background color like `.ui-slider-range{background: green;}`.

How can i manage this whith PF component slider? is this even possible? and what's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm working on a project and i don't want to mixed or include JS files in my code if not extremely necessary. But using PF slider i don't know how to make it, we can set PF slider attribute range to true but then we have 2 handlers (for min and max value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using javascript you can try to set the slider range attribute to true to display the two handles and than hide the first one via css.

You can try:

```
<p:slider range="true" for="zeroValue,sliderValue" styleClass="your-style-class"/>

<h:inputHidden id="zeroValue" value="0"/>
<h:inputHidden id="sliderValue"/>
```

css

```
.your-style-class span:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, works perfect! Can't believe i couldn't figure that by myself ;D

Comment: Creative! I like thinking out of the box